# rpart: how to remove the "long" labels

Tags: r, tree, label, rpart, cart-analysis

I am wondering is there any way that I can remove the **(long)** `labels` in my `tree`.
For example, in the following `tree` I would not to **remove** the `label` for the `branch #6` *i.e.* `Clarity =l1,Sl2,Sl1,VS2`

```
library(rpart.plot)
library(rpart)
data(diamonds)

    fit <- rpart(price ~ carat + cut + clarity, diamonds, method = "anova")
    rpart.plot(fit, type = 2, nn=T, extra = 101)
```

[image]

FYI, in reality in my data the label of one branch is `ID` and it goes from *one side of the image to the other!* That's why I want to find a way to only not show the label but the tree would stay!

Any help with explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could try playing with the parameters `varlen`, `faclen` and `cex` - see `?rpart.plot` for details.